# Mixed integer programming R: Least absolute deviation with cost associated with each regressor

Tags: r, regression, mixed-integer-programming

I have been presented with a problem, regarding the minimization of the absolute error, the problem know as LAD(Least absolute deviation) but, being each regressor the result of expensive test with an associated cost, one should refrain from using regressors that don't explain variance to a high degree. It takes the following equations:

[image]

Where N is the total number of observations, E the deviation associated with observation i,  S the number of independant variables, lambda a penalty coefficient for the cost, and C the cost associated with performing the test.

So far, I have oriented as usual. To make it lineal, I transformed the absolute value in two errors, e^+ and e^-, where e= y_i-(B_0+sum(B_j*X_ij) and the following constraints:

- z_j ={0,1}, binary value about whether the regressor enters my model.
- B_i<=M_zj; B_i>=-M_zj
- E^+, E^- >=0

A toy subset of data I'm working has the following structure:
For y

```
 quality
1       5
2       5
3       5
4       6
5       7
6       5
```

For the regressors

```
fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid
1           7.5            0.610        0.26
2           5.6            0.540        0.04
3           7.4            0.965        0.00
4           6.7            0.460        0.24
5           6.1            0.400        0.16
6           9.7            0.690        0.32
```

And for the cost

```
fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid
1          0.26              0.6        0.52
```

So far, my code looks like this:

```
# loading the matrixes
y <- read.csv(file="PATH\\y.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") #dim=100*11
regresores <- read.csv(file="PATH\\regressors.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")#dim=100*1
cost <- read.csv(file="PATH\\cost.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")#dim=1*11

for  (i in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)){#so as to have a collection of models with          different penalties
  obj.fun <- c(1,1,i*coste)
  constr <- matrix(
    c(y,regresores,-regresores),
    c(-y,-regresores,regresores),
    sum(regresores),ncol = ,byrow = TRUE)
  constr.dir <- c("<=",">=","<=","==")
  rhs<-c(regresores,-regresores,1,binary)
  sol<- lp("min", obj.fun, constr, constr.tr, rhs)
  sol$objval
  sol$solution}
```

I know theres is a LAD function in R, but for consistence sake with my colleagues, as well as a pretty annoying phD tutor, I have to perform this using `lpSolve` in R. I have just started with R for the project and I don't know exactly why this won't run. Is there something wrong with the syntax or my formulation of the model. Right know, the main problem I have is:

> "Error in matrix(c(y, regressors, -regressors), c(-y, -regressors, regressors),  : non-numeric matrix extent".

Mainly, I intended for it to create said weighted LAD model and have it return the different values of lambda, from 0 to 1 in a 0.1 step.

Thanks in advance and sorry for any inconvenience, neither English nor R are my native languages.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, just realized I forgot the most important part. I'll edit it now.

Comment: It helps us help you if you provide 1) the smallest amount of code possible to demonstrate the problem, 2) data for that code to run on, 3) an explicit statement of expected results, 4) an explanation of why your code doesn't work (e.g., how are the results different from the desired output or what error messages do you receive).

Comment: 2)the data is kind of massive, it is a matrix of 11*100 samples.3) I wish to have result showing, for each lambda, a model to work with.4) the code has given me some different errors, the main one being non-numeric matrix extend.1) The code I provided, is it not showing? Otherwise I don´t know exactly what it is supposed to be.

Comment: The code *is* showing, I'm just explaining what a complete question looks like. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.) If you can't provide all the data, provide a subset or a toy data set that can be used to demonstrate the problem. There are lots of data sets [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) for this sort of thing. Also, edit your question to include the exact error messages you receive. If you provide a well-structured question, you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll update my question. Sorry about all the inconvenience, I'm still a newbie to stackoverflow

Comment: @AaronG. No worries! Hopefully, we can come up with a solution.